sed regex, match first instance between varied delimeters
I have a set of hashes that I want to anonymize. Using GNU sed (v4.9), how can I replace only parts of the hash with something else? Specifically for my case, I want to preserve the $ symbol if it exists, but only if it is directly in front of the :.
(sed is not necessarily a requirement. Other commands that can do this, while accepting piped input, would work just as well. I just need this to work on the cli as part of a chain of piped commands. So not split over multiple lines is preferred)
Example:
USER:1234:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
COMPUTER$:4321:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
DOMAIN\bleh:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::
DOMAIN\$why:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::

Using the following command I am almost able to get what I want
sed 's/[^$:]\+/REDACTED/1'

REDACTED:1234:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED$:4321:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::
REDACTED$why:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::

However, as can be seen, this sed regex matches the last entry wrong. It should instead be
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::

The sed command should replace anything between the start of line ^ and $: OR :.
I don't know what I'm doing wrong. I have tried and tried to get the "or" clause to work properly using grouping and lookahead/behind and escaping characters but I can't get the result I want. From what I understand sed uses basic regex by default, but I can't seem to find the solution using -E or -r either...

Your problem here is your pattern: [^$:]\+ This pattern matches one or more characters that ARE NOT a dollar sign ($) OR a colon (:)

the ^ inside the square brackets means a negation of whatever follows it

More to the point, the square brackets match exactly one character. If you have multiple characters inside the square brackets, in any order, it matches one of them (or with negation, any character except one of those).

@tripleee in this case the square brackets are followed by "one-or-more" \+ so it matches all characters up to a $ or : then stops matching.

Of course; I'm just reacting to the emphasis in the previous comments on other aspects of the explanation than what I think is the OP's apparent misunderstanding.

Is sed a requirement? Processing delimited lists is usually easier with awk.

Are $s inside the first field always preceded by \ as in DOMAIN\$why?

Unknown. I was expecting to only find $ right before the colon so the last entry example surprised me when I saw it in real data. I would assume $ can appear anywhere in the user field based on this. This is the NT hash format btw. oguz's answer seems to handle what I need. The purpose of this was to anonymize the usernames, while still allowing the identification of whether the hash belongs to a user or computer account

For posterity, this is NTLM hash format, not NT hash. I can't edit my prior comment.

This works for me:
$ sed 's/^[^:]*[^:$]/REDACTED/' file
REDACTED:1234:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED$:4321:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::


An edge case <<<'aaa$$:bbb' sed 's/^[^:]*[^:$]/REDACTED/'

Unclear from the OP how that should be handled however?

NTLM hash format states that computer accounts must end with a $, which is what I am trying to differentiate from user accts while still anonymizing which user/computer the hash belongs to. I have never encountered $$: but I also hadn't encountered a $ anywhere besides at the end of the first field before, so maybe it's possible? I'm personally not concerned about this edge case coming up, but I guess the best way to handle it would be to change Computer$$:1234 to REDACTED$:1234. Because I imagine Computer$$ would denote a computer acct named Computer$

@ExecutionByFork awk is a better choice then awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{$1="REDACTED"($1~/\$$/?"$":"")}1'

A Perl:
perl -lpE 's/^[^:]*?(\$?:)/REDACTED\1/' file

Or, as suggested, a lookahead:
perl -lpE 's/^[^:]*?(?=\$?:)/REDACTED/' file 

Or, an awk:
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}
    NF>1 {$1= "REDACTED" ($1~/[$]$/ ? "$" : "")} 
1' file

Any of those print:
REDACTED:1234:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED$:4321:aad3b435b:abcdef:::
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::
REDACTED:5678:eaad3b4:fedcba:::

A key consideration is what happens if fields do not contain a delimiter. All three of these solutions require at least one : delimiter or the original line is unaltered.

Is this also possible using a lookahead?

@oguzismail: Good suggestion! Edited.

$1= "REDACTED" ($1~/[$]$/ ? "$" : "") to avoid writing REDACTED twice.

This might work for you (GNU sed):
sed 's/$:/:\n/;s/^[^:]*/REDACTED/;s/:\n/$:/' file

Replace $: with :\n, substitute as before then replace :\n with $:.
